# Need to find another approach to query search results in Laravel/PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I am having a really tough time figuring out another approach to do search querys on my site. At the moment i have search critierias for "Min size, Max size, City, street, Min. price, Max. price.

So i have these queries (build using Laravel standard):

```
if (!empty($by) && empty($adresse) && empty($minstor) && empty($maxstor)) 
        {
            $users = User::where('pris', '<', $maxpris)->where('pris', '>', $minpris)->where('by', '=', $by)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
        }
        elseif (!empty($by) && !empty($adresse) && empty($minstor) && empty($maxstor)) 
        {
            $users = User::where('pris', '<', $maxpris)->where('pris', '>', $minpris)->where('by', '=', $by)->where('adresse', '=', $adresse)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
        }
        elseif (empty($by) && !empty($adresse) empty($minstor) && empty($maxstor)) 
        {
            $users = User::where('pris', '<', $maxpris)->where('pris', '>', $minpris)->where('adresse', '=', $adresse)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
        }
        else
        {
            $users = User::where('pris', '<', $maxpris)->where('pris', '>', $minpris)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
        }
```

All of this simply for the user being able to search for the for the critirias above, but if i want to add several more feautures, i can just imagine how many different `if functions` i will need to run in order to get all the specific inputs etc. It will evovle eksponentially really quick.

How can i get around this problem without having to create hundreds of different `if else` statements in order to return the correct query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set up an array of your filters with their corresponding operator. Then iterate over the filters that were passed and running the them (This hasn't been tested but should get you headed in the right direction):

```
$available_queries = [
    ['input' => 'maxpris', 'operator' => '<', 'field' => 'pris'],
    ['input' => 'minpris', 'operator' => '>', 'field' => 'pris'],
    ['input' => 'by',      'operator' => '=', 'field' => 'by'],
    ['input' => 'adresse', 'operator' => '=', 'field' => 'addresse'],
]

$query = User::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');

foreach($available_queries as $filter){
    if(request()->input($filter['input'])){
        $query = $query->where(
            $filter['field'],
            $filter['operator'],
            request()->input($filter['input'])
        );
    }
}

$users = $query->get();
```

EDIT: I found an error in my original script. Updated to fix the error and make more readable.

Comment: Hi Patrick, works perfect right out of the box! Awesome, and thanks for your support! :)

Comment: All the same you need to put inputs in array. To group inputs is the better way.

Answer (score 2):

You can to do like this

```
    $q = User::query();

    if (\Input::has('name')) {
        $q->where('name', \Input::get('name')); 
    }
    if (\Input::has('address')) {
        $q->where('address', \Input::get('address')); 
    }

    ...
```

You can iterate it in loop like this,

```
  foreach($request->all() as $req_field => $req_data) {
      if (\Input::has($req_field)) {
        $q->where($req_field, \Input::get($req_field)); 
    }
  }
```

p.s. or you can iterate it in scope ...

then

```
   $items = $q->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

Comment: Since the OP specifically requested not having a bunch of `if` statements, I think you should show an example of your suggestion of iterating in a loop.

Comment: Hi Yurich, thanks for your answer. But what if the input has both the name  and address, but not a min. size, but a max price? How would i be able to build that without tons of writing the same code with few changes?

Comment: Hi again Yurich, thanks for your update, i see the idea - however how would i check if a value is less than, bigger than, or equal to? For example, for a min. price and max. price, i want to get the users in between the min. and max. price?

Comment: @Patrick , You need to make the different conditions for max and min and       inputs like name and address. It's too hard to put different conditions in one loop.

Comment: @Patrick You can make all you conditions, [laravel tutorials](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#advanced-wheres). For example between   ->whereBetween('votes', [1, 100])